# how to run multiple commands in Kubernetes pod in specific path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, wso2-identity-server

I want to run two different commands in two different location inside the kubernetes pod. How can I do it. My approach is below;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wso2is-deployment
  namespace: tech-ns
  labels:
    app: wso2is
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wso2is
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wso2is
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: vialogic/wsois:cluster1.0
          name: wso2is
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security/; /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/", "-c"]
          args: ["keytool -exportcert -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -rfc -file wso2carbon.pem; keytool -import -alias wso2Carbon -file wso2carbon.pem -keystore cacerts"]
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "2000m"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "4000m"
                     volumeMounts:
              ...
```

let me explain you what I want to achieve in above manifest. I have two commands one `keytool -exportcert -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -rfc -file wso2carbon.pem` i want to execute this command on `/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security/`, and the second command is `keytool -import -alias wso2Carbon -file wso2carbon.pem -keystore cacerts` in location `/opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/`.

When i apply the manifest it fail to create the container. when I describe the pod. it says.

```
Message:      failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security/; /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/": stat /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security/; /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass your multiple commands as a shell script embedded in a call to `sh -c`, like this:

```
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
    cd /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.11.0/repository/resources/security/
    keytool -exportcert -alias wso2carbon -keystore wso2carbon.jks -rfc -file wso2carbon.pem

    cd /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/
    keytool -import -alias wso2Carbon -file wso2carbon.pem -keystore cacerts
```

(Note that we're not using `args`.)

This will work, but it doesn't entirely make sense; the pod will exit as soon as these commands have completed. For a `Deployment`, you would typically expect to see your containers executing some sort of long-running command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after putting the command in deployment script and run the manifest then it run the pod successfully, when executing the command it require password by throwing the below logs `Enter keystore password:  
 Certificate stored in file <wso2carbon.pem>
 Enter keystore password:  Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
 Enter keystore password:  Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
 Enter keystore password:  Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
 Too many failures - try later`

Comment: I think we have to provide password as well after executing the command.

Comment: "How do I non-interactively provide a password to the `keytool` command?" seems like a different question.

Comment: Would add to this the recommendation for PostStart LifeCycle Hooks: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

Comment: Including it directly in your image as an entrypoint wrapper script could also be a good approach.

Comment: Use environment variables to pass the password to the pod and you can refer it in your keytool command